# Cannot figure out how to display correct output (Code included)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I cannot seem to figure out how to display the correct output. When I run my query it is supposed to say "eBook" for the correct format. However, I can only get it to display the assigned number corresponding to the "eBook" format which is 1. I need it to display "eBook" instead of the number. It is probably a really easy fix but I am new to VB and just need another set of eyes and a helping hand.

```
    Private Sub btnEBooks_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEBooks.Click
    Dim Q = From book In books
            Let format = book.Format
            Let formatName = GetFormatName(book.Format)
            Where format = 1
            Order By book.Title
            Select book.Author, book.Format, book.Title, book.YearPublished

    dgvOutput.DataSource = Q.ToList
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub
Function GetFormatName(FNum As Integer) As String
    If FNum = 1 Then

        Return "eBook"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Try putting the `Where format = 1` just after `From book In books`, and see if it changes anything.

Comment: No, it gives me a syntax error and wants to turn it into `Where Format() = 1`

Comment: My bad, it should be `Where book.format = 1`

Comment: so do what you just said except change it to `book.format = 1`?

Comment: Still only showing the number 1

Comment: You're selecting the `book.Format`, try this: `Select book.Author, formatName, book.Title, book.YearPublished`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I knew it was something simple!